# I created a list of functions in R. The functions in the list do not behave the same way as the functions written independently

Tags: r, list, function

The data below is a simplified version of a much larger data set.

I have the following list of three data frames, named df.list:

```
> part.1<-data.frame(c(1,2,3,4), c(5,6,7,8),c(9,10,11,12))
>part.2<-data.frame(c(1,2,3,1),c(5,4,7,1),c(9,4,10,1))
> part.3<-data.frame(c(2,2,3,3),c(2,2,7,7),c(2,2,10,10))
> colnames(part.1)<-c("a","b","c")
> colnames(part.2)<-c("a","b","c")
> colnames(part.3)<-c("a","b","c")
> df.list<-list(part.1,part.2,part.3)
```

I would like to see if each of the rows in another data frame, named df.primary, exactly matches any of the rows in the three data frames in df.list, with each data frame from df.list considered separately.

My desired final output is a list of character vectors (one vector for each data frame in df.list, length of vectors corresponding to number of rows in df.primary) reading "yes" or "no" depending on if there is an exact match in df.primary. I name the list final.yes.no.list in the code below.

I wrote the following code to do this:

```
> df.primary<-data.frame(c(1,1,3,3), c(5,5,7,7), c(9,9,10,10))

> a1.list<-alist(x=,y=,z=, c(for (i in 1:4){if(x==as.numeric(df.list[[1]]$a[i]) & y==as.numeric(df.list[[1]]$b[i]) & z==as.numeric(df.list[[1]]$c[i])){a<-"yes"}else{a<-"no"}}, return(a)))
> b1.list<-alist(x=,y=,z=, c(for (i in 1:4){if(x==as.numeric(df.list[[2]]$a[i]) & y==as.numeric(df.list[[2]]$b[i]) & z==as.numeric(df.list[[2]]$c[i])){a<-"yes"}else{a<-"no"}}, return(a)))
> c1.list<-alist(x=,y=,z=, c(for (i in 1:4){if(x==as.numeric(df.list[[3]]$a[i]) & y==as.numeric(df.list[[3]]$b[i]) & z==as.numeric(df.list[[3]]$c[i])){a<-"yes"}else{a<-"no"}}, return(a)))

> combo<-list(a1.list,b1.list,c1.list)
> function.list<-lapply(combo,as.function)

> final.yes.no.list<-list()
> for(j in 1:3)
+ {
+ final.yes.no.list[[j]]<-mapply(function.list[[j]],as.list(df.primary$e), as.list(df.primary$f),as.list(df.primary$g))
+ print(final.yes.no.list[[j]])
+ }

> str(final.yes.no.list)
 List of 3
 $ : chr [1:4] "no" "no" "no" "no"
 $ : chr [1:4] "no" "no" "no" "no"
 $ : chr [1:4] "no" "no" "yes" "yes"
```

The output isn't what I want for the first and second vectors in final.yes.no.list, but it is right for the last vector in the list.

It should be (I modified the output below to look like I want it to):

```
> str(final.yes.no.list)
List of 3
 $ : chr [1:4] "yes" "yes" "no" "no"
 $ : chr [1:4] "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes"
 $ : chr [1:4] "no" "no" "yes" "yes"
```

When I write function.list[[1]] as an independent function (to evaluate the first data frame in df.list), named function.1, it gives the desired output.

```
> function.1<-function(x,y,z)
+ {
+ {for (i in 1:4)
+ {
+ if(x==as.numeric(df.list[[1]]$a[i]) & y==as.numeric(df.list[[1]]$b[i]) & z==as.numeric(df.list[[1]]$c[i]))
+ {a<-"yes"}
+ else{a<-"no"}
+ return(a)
+ }
+ }
+ }

> mapply(function.1, df.primary$e, df.primary$f,df.primary$g)
[1] "yes" "yes" "no"  "no"
```

In contrast, function.list[[1]] gives the following:

```
> mapply(function.list[[1]], df.primary$e, df.primary$f,df.primary$g)
[1] "no" "no" "no" "no"
```

Does anyone have an explanation for why function.list[[1]] and function.1 give different outputs, and/or a suggestion on how to make function.list[[1]] give the correct output; that is, the same output as function.1?
A better way code to achieve my desired output would also be welcome.

Comment: Take a careful look at how mapply "loops" and what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it:

```
check_rows <- function(df.ref, dfs.check){
    ref_rows <- apply(X=df.ref, MARGIN=1,
                      FUN=function(row) paste(row, collapse='-'))
    lapply(X=dfs.check, FUN=function(df.check){
        df_rows <- apply(X=df.check, MARGIN=1,
                         FUN=function(row) paste(row, collapse='-'))
        ifelse(df_rows %in% ref_rows, 'yes', 'no')
    })
}

check_rows(df.ref=df.primary, dfs.check=df.list)

check_rows(df.ref=df.primary, dfs.check=df.list[1])
```